# Get request returning blank response

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery

I am trying to call a url using ajax. it works well using browser but while calling through ajax it return blank.
Anyone please help. Thanks in advance below is code i am using..

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({

type: "get",
            dataType:"json",
            crossDomain :true,
            url: "http://cloud1.autoweek.com/widgets/test-read-more/get-article-json.php?nodeid=54321&start=123123123",
            success: function(response){ 
                alert("success");
            },
            complete:function(){
                    alert("complete");
            },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                        console.log(textStatus);

        }
        }); 


});
</script>
```

Comment: try type:"post" and alert the response

Comment: Asifa, I tried but it also returning blank.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/sLFTr/ you can search more on this line. I think only 10 percent work is left. You can try a bit. Also check http://jsfiddle.net/yVqpS/